# Rails validate error not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app with this validate in the `costquestion` model:

```
  validate :estimatesource

  private

  def estimatesource
    if !(source_contractor? ^ source_other? ^ source_sqft_cost? ^ source_rs_means? ^ source_facilities_management?)
      errors.add(:base, "Specify Estimate Source")
    end
  end
```

In the form, I have this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @costquestion, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}, :validate => true do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
```

At the top of the page it displays "Some errors were found, please take a look:". I don't see the "Some errors were found, please take a look:" error.

How can I get it to display?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleForm highlights fields with errors that are visible. To display errors attached to `base`, you could use [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Errors-not-connected-with-visible-fields):

```
<%= f.error :base %>
```

Or you can create your own helper to display list of errors at the top

```
<%- if @costquestion.errors.any? %>
  <%- @costquestion.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     <%= message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```